# How to check if array[] has a null value in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am reading a csv file. One of the requirements is to check if a certain column has a value or not. In this case I want to check the value in `array[18]`. However, I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
```

Is there any other way to check the array index if it has a value or empty?

My code:

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine())!= null) { 

    String[] record = sCurrentLine.split(",");   

    if(record.length > 0){ // checking if the current line is not empty on the file
       if(record[18] != null){ // as per console, I am getting the error in this line
          String readDateRecord = record[18];
          // other processing here
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: get the length of the array first and you can avoid IndexOutfBoundsException.Or else catch the ArrayOutofBoundsException

Comment: The exception says there is no element at this position in array. Show us the code where you add elements to array.

Comment: First check the `record.length - 1 == 18`

Comment: Is there a reason you arbitrarily accessed the 18 element? (need more code)

Comment: I updated the content to provide some codes

Comment: @user3864004 why 18?? there is no index 18 in your array.i

Comment: The reason I am checking the value of the 18th element is because, when this is empty, I will create an error file saying that this should have a value.

Comment: @user3864004  put `System.out.println(record.length)`  you will see length is less than 19 .so there is no element at 18th index .

Answer (score 2):

Look, according to [JavaSE7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown to indicate that an array has
>   been accessed with an illegal index. (In your case) The index is
>   greater than or equal to the size of the array.

Means, the index `18` is not legal for array `record` in your code. Moreover if the array `record` is `null` then you will get another exception called `NullPointerException`.

To overcome your problem, there are many solutions, one can be

```
//assuming that record is initialized 
if(record.length > 18){
      String readDateRecord = record[18];
      ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here one approach is this

```
Object array[] = new Object[18];
boolean isempty = true;
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] != null) {
    isempty = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code snippet -

```
int length = record.length;   
if( (n>0 && n<length-1) && record[n] != null ){

   String readDateRecord = record[n];
   //other processing here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Integer [] record = {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1};
    for(int i = 0; i < record.length; i++)
        if(record[i] == null) {
            System.out.println(i+1 + " position is null");
        }
}
```

Comment: This will simply print `"null is null"`, which seems pretty silly. Better add the index `i` to that println

Answer (score 0):

Size is fixed in array after creation .if you get index beyond of size then it's generated `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` .So first you need to get the size of array then retrive the value from array

```
 int size=record.length;
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
   if(record[i] != null){
     // other processing here
   }
 }
```

Declare an array with size “n” and access the n-th element. However, as we already mentioned, the indices of an array with size “n”, reside in the interval [0, n – 1].

Answer (score -2):

If its an arrayList then check if it contains null

```
array.contains(null));
```